# Why getHeight of ImageView is lower by 30 pixels than actual size?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview

My task is to fit image in ImageView and keep aspect ratio. So I need to crop the image to keep ImageView aspect ratio.

I have image from camera in size 320x240.
My screen size is 480x320 (landscape mode)
Application works only landscape mode, but no fullscreen.

ImageView fill parent. Layout XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:keepScreenOn="true" android:scaleType="fitCenter">
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

With image.getWidth() and image.getHeight() I get 480x270 size.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    MySize msize = main.imageSize();

    //msize.height += 30; <----this fix my problem, but I dont undersand why?

    Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

    double kw = (double)size.width / (double)msize.width;
    double kh = (double)size.height / (double)msize.height;

    double k = Math.min(kw, kh);

    Log.d("INFO", "msize before" + msize);

    msize.width = (int)Math.ceil(msize.width * k);
    msize.height = (int)Math.ceil(msize.height * k);

    int left = (size.width - msize.width) / 2;
    int top = (size.height - msize.height) / 2;

    Log.d("INFO", "msize " + msize);
    Log.d("INFO", "size " + size.width + "x" + size.height);

    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width, size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(left, top, msize.width, msize.height), 80, baos);
    byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
    main.updateImage(image);
}
```

where msize is ImageView size, and size is Camera picture size. After this, camera image will be croped to: 320x180, and result is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e2xwdc6m88ty34/SC20120705-121813.png

If I add 30 to ImageView height, I got right result.

My Android is 2.3.3.